# Does the DoubleClick Google Analytics integration support Cross Domain Tracking?

Tags: google-analytics

I have one more question about the GA / Doubleclick integration - does it support cross domain tracking?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Display Advertiser Support (using dc.js instead of ga.js) then yes, it does (don't have a written source but I'm using it with a multiple domain setup and everything works fine).

Comment: Hi - can you elaborate on your configuration? we have the

Comment: Addition to above: We have the _gaq.push(['_link','http://www.destination.com']); on the source.com, are seeing the `_utma` codes being sent through the url to destination.com (however the cookie being set at destination.com is not the same as the value passed through the url). On destination.com have _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'source.com']); but are not seeing the referrer in the hit to destination as the original referrer to source. Any help greatly appreciated.